# Understanding BinningProcess output

Tags: python, scikit-learn, preprocessor, optbinning

I want to integrate `optbinning.BinningProcess` in my Pipeline but before, I need to understand the output. I was expecting bins after fit_transform but I obtained values close to my target variable.

Can someone explain the output to me, please? Or point out to me if I am doing something wrong.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
from random import choices
from random import uniform
from optbinning import BinningProcess

df = pd.DataFrame({'continuous_feature': choices(range(0,30), k=100),
                    'cat_feature': choices(['A', 'B', 'C'], k = 100),
                     'target' : [uniform(15,16) for x in range(0,100)]})
all_features = ["continuous_feature", "cat_feature"]

X = df.loc[:, all_features]
y = df.loc[:, 'target']

BinningProcess(all_features, categorical_variables= ['cat_feature']).fit_transform(X, y)
```

Comment: Not sure, because I haven't used this before, but I think it's intended to bin each input variable separately, then replace each bin with the average of the target variable for that bin. If there's no correlation between the input variable and the output, the output of this transform will be values close to the mean of the target variable.

Comment: Thank you. I did not get that part: "replace each bin with the average of the target variable for that bin". I wish I could have the bins instead :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Nick ODell, for each bin, the value returned by the binning algorithm are "the average of the target variable for that bin". If you are willing to obtain the bins instead, use the option `metric = "bins"` in `fit.transform(X,y)`.